# How Can I generate a PDF from my form in clicking in save-draft and save it in directory

Tags: pdf-generation, orbeon

I modified `properties-form-runner.xml` with this code:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-draft.*.*">
    pdf
    then save
    then success-message("save-draft-success")
    recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

but it doesn't work. I see the action runner "send" but I don't know how to integrate in the code.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."

Comment: Lebki, as mentioned by EJoshuaS, could you tell us more what you are trying to achieve in this process? You mention `send()`; would you like to submit the data to a service you have in the backend? Then, I imagine that you should have a call to the [`send()` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#send) in this process. -Alex

Comment: when i click in the button save draft  a error message was shown , iwant when iclick in this button a pdf is generated and the form is saved . Besides i want that pdf was saved in a directory

Comment: Currently it's not possible to save to a directly. With Orbeon Forms 2016.2 you can [Submitting a PDF file to an external service](http://blog.orbeon.com/2016/08/submitting-pdf-file-to-external-service.html) though.